# Differential equations and exponential growth

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I was reading about differential equations and got stuck in a small detail that I can't make peace with.

If a population doubles every unit of time, I would write

$$ \frac{dP}{dt}=2P $$

which by separation of variables would yield

$$ P=P(0)e^{2t} $$

But I also know intuitively that I should have

$$ P = P(0)e^{(ln2)t} = P(0)2^{t}$$

which suggests the factor in the differential equation should be $\ln2$ instead of 2. What's wrong with my logic?

Thanks!

EDIT: This is the part of the textbook that confused me. 
Doesn't it confuse discrete and continuous cases as well?

[image: Example that was confusing]

Comment: **Try *proving* that if $P(0) = 1$ and $P'(t) = 2P(t)$ then $P(1) = 2$ to see where the problem is.**

Comment: @JoaoMarcos  If you are ok, you can accept the answer and set as solved. Thanks!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The "intuitive" answer $P=P_02^n$ is only correct in a discrete system. It is the solution to the discrete functional equation $P_{n+1}=2P_n.$ If the population doubles at the end of every unit of time, then indeed the discrete solution is correct, where $n$ is the number of discrete time units. A natural number.

However in the differential equation $$\frac{dP}{dt}=2P$$ we are not saying that population doubles after a finite amount of time. Instead we're saying the instantaneous derivative matches twice the population. The proportional increase in population after an *infinitesimal* amount of time is an infinitesimal twice as big. $dP=2P\,dt.$ It's a totally different statement, and the intuition about discrete systems does not apply.

To relate a discrete time system to a continuous time system some limiting process has to take place, which is where the number $e$ comes in. If we imagine dividing up each time unit up into $n$ intervals, and let the population increase $2/n$-fold each interval, so after one sub interval the population goes to $P_0+2P_0/n$, etc, then at the end of the $n$ subintervals the population is

$$
P=P_0\left(1+\frac{2}{n}\right)^n.
$$

The limit as $n\to\infty$ of the expression in the parentheses is $e^2$. That is essentially the definition of the number $e$. So what started as a doubling in the discrete case becomes and 7.38-fold increase in the continuum limit. And more generally, that's what the number $e$ does: it changes base discrete geometric growth $a^t$ into continuous exponential growth $e^{at}.$

Because of this translation between discrete and continuous, a continuous exponential growth problem which matches the discrete "doubling growth" problem at discrete times has to have $dP/dt=(\log2) P.$

Or alternatively, a discrete geometric growth problem that matches a continuous exponential growth problem with growth rate $2$ ($dP/dt=2P$) must follow $P_{n}=e^2P_{n-1}$ instead of doubling.

Comment: Could you explain what do you mean by limiting process and how that and $e$ would connect the discrete and the continuous cases?

Comment: @JoãoMarcos I added some details to my answer. Does it help explain?

Comment: Thanks and I apologize for the delay to reply. I have edited my question with an image of a textbook that confused me. Doesn't it confuse discrete and continuous cases too?

Comment: @JoãoMarcos No, the text in the attached image only considers continuous growth.

Answer (score 7):

You are mixing discrete-time with continuous-time problems. For discrete-time problems, we use difference equations rather than differential equations. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_difference_equation for more information on difference equations (or recurrence relations).

Your case corresponds to a geometric progression defined by the following recurrence relationship (or difference equation):
$$P_{t+1}=2P_{t} \implies P_{t}=P_02^t.$$

Answer (score 4):

The differential equation:

$$\frac{dP}{dt}=2P$$

take into account infinitesimal growth of the population continuosly in time, whereas the equation:

$$P = P(0)2^{t}$$

is valid in a discrete time increment context.

Comment: But shouldn't the continuous cases just be an extension of the discrete?

Comment: in the continuos case in each instant the increment dP is added to P, for this reason the growth is bigger whereas in the discrete case the addition is done at each discrete unit of time

Comment: the concept is analogous to the compound interest https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compound_interest

Answer (score 4):

Your second reasoning is correct. Exactly for the reason that you worked out. "The population doubles every unit of time" has the differential equation
$$
\frac{dP}{dt}=\ln(2)P
$$
More generally, "The population increases by r% every unit of time" has the continuous dynamical model
$$
\frac{dP}{dt}=\ln(1+r/100)P
$$

Or seen another way, doubling per time unit is equal to increase by a factor of $\sqrt 2$ every half time unit or by $2^{1/n}$ every $n$th part of a time unit. Which means that
$$
\frac{P((k+1)/n)-P(k/n)}{1/n}=n(2^{1/n}-1)P(k/n)
$$
and the limit of the factor in the last expression is $\ln(2)$.